# Is the DRF ModelSerializer faster or slower than the standard Serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

At work we tend to stay away from using the ModelSerializer in the Django Rest Framework. From what I have heard it is said to be faster in some respects. Is this the case?

And what are the advantages of using the standard serializer instead of the ModelSerializer?

Comment: `ModelSerializer` _is_ just a `Serializer` with some extra fields, validators and the `create` and `update` method. If you need these, use it. If you don't need them, don't. Look at the source code if you're unsure: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/9ee67bbff77638316b6f1455d5dff38637a02306/rest_framework/serializers.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now one of the main reasons that I have heard, after to talking to some people. Is that when it comes to using the ModelView, you have this issue where you have a number of API endpoints that can end up being redundant.

There is also a lot more to take care of too.

Answer (score 0):

ModelSerializer is used when you need to serialize a model while regular Serializer is used when you need to serialize certain information which might not be a model.

[Check this article](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#:%7E:text=The%20ModelSerializer%20class%20provides%20a,you%2C%20based%20on%20the%20model.)